# How to get the vertices of a rect() in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

Using the OpenCV for Processing library by Greg Borenstein, I am able to detect a user's face within a webcam stream, and draw a rectangle around it. Here is the portion that draws the rectangle to the screen:

```
Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect()

for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) 
{
   rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
}
```

As the user moves their face, the rectangle will move accordingly.

I want to draw a line on the screen where one point is set at *predefined location* and the other is always pinned to the *bottom right* hand vertex of the rectangle. This way the length and angle of the line will change with respect to the rectangle's location.

One thing I tried was to subtract some values from `faces[i].x` and `faces[i].y` until I reached the bottom right vertex, but I found that the depth of the face in the webcam made this method not work.

With that, how could I find the above mentioned vertex of the rectangle so that I can properly draw the line?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You're the one drawing the rectangle, so you already have its position. Can you please post a [mcve]? (note: this should **not** be your entire project, but just a small example that shows the problem)

Comment: @Kevin Workman Firstly, the rectangle is translating to a randomly selected point on the screen, therefore there would be no way for me to know where it will end up. Secondly, I didn't provide any code because I don't believe it is necessary to solve the problem. I'm just looking for some way to find the bottom right vertex of the rectangle.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  You're the one coming up with the random point, aren't you? Again, please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Kevin Workman I reworded the question, provided some example code, and kept everything to a minimum.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I edited the question. It has been reworded, and some example code has been provided. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` position of a rectangle gives you its left side. So `x+width` gives you its right side.

Similarly, the `y` position of a rectangle gives you its top side. So `y+height` gives you its bottom side.

```
float rectRight = faces[i].x + faces[i].width;
float rectBottom = faces[i].y + faces[i].height;
```

If that's still not what you're looking for, then please post a small example that we can actually run. Use hardcoded values instead of relying on opencv, so we can copy and paste your code and see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your solution works. I would up-vote if I could, but I don't yet have enough reputation.

Comment: @JCorkhill No problem. For questions like these, I find that drawing out some examples on graph paper is very helpful. And you can always accept an answer if you found it helpful.